# Set position of radio button in table cell

Tags: html, css, radio-button, css-position

I've got a problem with the alignment of my radio button. I would like to set the position of the radio button freely, but with the code I have now I'm not able to set it properly.

It stays in the middle from the top and I can only changes the `margin-left`.
Can anyone help me?

You can find my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/3vL8Lgo9/

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<table class="divTable" border="1" cellspace="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:1134px; height:756px;">
  <tbody class="divTableBody">
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:900px; height:194px;" colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:234px; height:194px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td colspan="5" style="width:1134px; height:185px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow" style="padding-top:100px;">
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:140px; height:293px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
      </td>
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:251px; height:293px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:673px; height:293px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:1000px; height:84px;" colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:134px; height:84px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `vertical-align: bottom;` or `vertical-align: top;` on the `td to make it move up and down

Answer (score 0):

You want it in the middle;

```
.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  text-align:center;
}
```

or have i misunderstood you?

Comment: I want to move it freely in the tablecell to the position I want

Comment: with freely what do you mean ? . like move it around as with position?

Comment: Yes, I want it on a spot that I choose, what you normally could do with margin-left and top.

Comment: you can use: text-indent:30px; to force it, but if you want to move more freely you could make it with div and make a table with that

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.divTableCellRadioButton` to `position:relative`. Now set the input to `position:absolute` and define the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` position as you wish. The example below shows the radio button `20px` from the top of the container.

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTableCellRadioButton {
  position:relative;
}

.divTableCellRadioButton input {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="divTable" border="1" cellspace="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:1134px; height:756px;">
  <tbody class="divTableBody">
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:900px; height:194px;" colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:234px; height:194px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td colspan="5" style="width:1134px; height:185px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow" style="padding-top:100px;">
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:140px; height:293px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
      </td>
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:251px; height:293px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" rowspan="2" style="width:673px; height:293px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
      <td class="divTableCellRadioButton" style="width:35px; height:146px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divTableRow">
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:1000px; height:84px;" colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="divTableCell" style="width:134px; height:84px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```